# efficient and accurate matrix search method in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm brushing off my MATLAB skills, which haven't been used it a very long time. And to do so I've been doing the puzzles over at project eueler. Well, I'm kind of stumped on this one as everything seems to run fine when I break into parts but my greatest number is apparently not correct.

Anyway here's my code
        %This script will take a grid and find the greatest product of 4 numbers
        %up, down, left right, and diagonal

```
    %create the grid
    grid = [08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08;
    49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00;
    81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65;
    52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91;
    22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80;
    24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50;
    32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70;
    67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21;
    24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72;
    21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95;
    78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92;
    16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57;
    86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58;
    19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40;
    04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66;
    88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69;
    04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36;
    20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16;
    20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54;
    01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48;];

    %grid(row, column)

    %find how many rows and columns there are
    [rowNum, columnNum] = size(grid);

    %Current greatest product of four consecutive
    greatest = 0;

    %test left right

    %iterate through all rows
    for i = 1:rowNum
        %iterate through all columns except the last tthree
        for x = 1:columnNum-3
            %test the consecutive numbers starting with the current colum
            %iteration
            current = 1;
            for test = x:x+3
                current = current * grid(i, test);
                if greatest < current
                    greatest = current;
                end
            end
        end
    end

    %iterate through all columns
    for i = 1:columnNum
        %iterate throw all rows except the last three
        for x = 1:rowNum-3
            %test the consecutive numbers starting with the current colum
            %iteration
            current = 1;
            for test = x:x+3
                current = current * grid(test, i);
                if greatest < current
                    greatest = current;
                end
            end
        end
    end

    for i = 1:columnNum-3
        %iterate throw all column except the last two
        for x = 1:rowNum-3
            %test the consecutive numbers starting with the current colum
            %iteration
            current = 1;

            %count adds the number of iterations to the row number in grid
            %forcing it to move in a diagonal line
            count = 0;

            %test consecutively from x to three to the right
            for test = x:x+3

                %make new current product
                current = current * grid(i+count, test);

                %add to count to shift down one row next iteration
                count = count + 1;

                %check for greatest
                if greatest < current
                    greatest = current;
                end
            end
        end
    end
    disp(greatest)
```

I think the problem lies in the nested for loops searching the diagonal, but I'm not sure. 
I've broken it up into pieces (test each for loop on its own and it it output each element as it searched through them). I'm pretty sure the horizontal and vertical search method works correctly.

Just wanted a fresh set of eyes to look at this, Thanks!

Also I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this so if anyone has some ideas for a better algorithm I'd love to hear it!

Comment: I remember this problem! Are you checking diagonals that go from the bottom left to the top right as well as ones like the example?

Comment: Nope! That was the problem, I realized I was only checking in one diagonal direction a little while after I posted. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question, you want to check per each grid element which 4 out of the 8 nearest neighbors product is the biggest?